# Synonymise [osx-high-sierra] and [macos-high-sierra]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Please make [osx-high-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-high-sierra) (108 questions) a synonym of [macos-high-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-high-sierra) (710 questions).

Official name is **macOS High Sierra** according to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180907061629/https://www.apple.com/macos/high-sierra).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is clearly appropriate, and is now done:

## [macos-high-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-high-sierra) ← [osx-high-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-high-sierra)